# Buildozer keep crashing for different ModuleNotFoundError reasons

Tags: kivy, python-3.8, buildozer, kivymd, modulenotfounderror

Ok, I know there are other posts but couldn´t relate to none, so, bare with me here

Why I'm not posting code: happened in multiple codes

I have all my imports on buildozer.spec file requirements as usual.

Simple applications I am able to run NP.

but I am actually developing a bigger app that connects to googlesheets to download data. (I don't think the problem is related to google though - other project that doesn't rely on that also crashes).

So I started to get really odd crashes like:
"ModuleNotFoundError: no module named imageio"

Ok, I have never asked to import imageio. But when I put imageio in the requirements (on buildozer.spec) suddenly other module is not found and this is going on forever.

Thinks worth notice: It is working on local OS (Ubuntu 20)
I am using a virtual environment.
Buildozer is able to build and install apk.

Is there anything I am missing? It has been going for months now and I was very reluctant to post as this is odd, but couldn't find anything searching for an answer. So, any help would be great!

I've tried using Python3.8 and 3.9

Answer (score 1):

This Is Common Problem For Beginners Who Are Using Other Third Party Modules And Getting **Module Not Found Error And The App Crashes**

This Occurs Because :

**--> Even Though You Used Only One Third Party Module - The Third Party Module Itself Has Other Third Party Modules in Them**

So Basically When You Add : Say for example : **torch**, it maybe using other third party modules like : **numpy**
So Even Though When You Add **torch** to **.spec file** , The app may crash by throwing a **Module Not Found Error [numpy]**.

The Solution To This Example Problem Is That : You Have To Add **numpy** in the **requirements in the .spec file**.

So, A Basic And Most Common Solution To This Kind Of Problem Is

**--> Run The App Everytime And Note Down Which Modules Are Not Found And Add that module in the .spec file**

When All The **Third Party Modules** Are Satisfied Your App Will Run As Butter :)

Comment: That was exactly my approach. Except that seems to fall in the realm of trial and error instead of actual problem solving. 

As I said. It keep asking for modules over and over. 

It seems to me that kivymd==0.104.1 (instead of version 0.104.2) solved the problem (ModuleNotFoundError problem).

Still having some in-app crashes, don't know if that's related though.

Comment: In App Crashes Maybe Caused Because Of Your Python Code , Because Kivy Checks All The Third Party Modules At First. Check Your Python Code And Seek if You Made An Errors:)

Comment: Yep. there was the common mistake of mixing spaces and tabs...  ><

Other than that, I keep having trouble with dependancies... I know I shouldn't just copy the contents of pip freeze, so... 

Is there any other way to check for the requirements section prior to the actual building that you are aware of? 

Cheers